# Функция возвращает undefined-переменную

Tags: node.js

Начал работу с библиотекой *'node-vk-bot-api'*. Ошибка возникает на моменте вызова метода getCbr() - он возвращает мне *undefined*, хотя в методе я возвращаю float-переменную. Спасибо. Буду рад любому Вашему совету.

Код:

```
async function getCbr() {
try {
    await fetch('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            let currency = data['Valute']['USD']['Value'];
            console.log(currency);
            return currency;
        });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`getCbr error: ${e}`);
}
}



bot.on(async(ctx) => {
    let cbr = await getCbr();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return currency; у вас внутри функции которую передаете в промис, но из функции getCbr() ничего не возвращается, потому и undefined. Достаточно добавить return перед await fetch.

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам за объяснение ошибки. Возможно, Вы опечатались и имели ввиду добавить return после await, потому что я решил эту проблему таким образом (инициализировав переменную до fetch и в нем её изменив)

Comment: @r1hsfoa можно const res = await fetch(...), потом return res. А можно сразу return fetch (await тогда и не нужен, хотя и с ним можно). Важно чтоб из getCbr любым способом что-то возвращалось.

Comment: Теперь понял к чему был return, сейчас попробую переделать (должна увеличиться читаемость). Еще раз Вам спасибо